# Is there an optimal way of recognising a non-defective Lucene index in a directory?

Tags: java, lucene

Just getting to grips with Lucene (currently using 4.6).

A Lucene index consists of various files (initially about 5, but can be fewer) in a directory.  They have quite cryptic names such as "_0.fdt", etc.

I'm just wondering if there is a general way of testing the contents of a directory to determine whether it is a non-corrupt and therefore usable Lucene index?  Perhaps assuming initially that v4.6 is the only possible version one might have to deal with...

The point being, really, that if an index can be seen to exist, and if it is determined to have been created or updated relatively recently, an algorithm might determine that there is probably no need to recreate the index... whereas if it is unreadable/unusable it will have to be deleted completely and rebuilt.

Anyone got any idea what I'm rabbitting on about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CheckIndex`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/CheckIndex.html) includes a lot of tools to get information about the health of the index, and repair segments.  The class can also be run as a command line tool, if that's more convenient, in your case, than writing code.

And, of course, attempting to open an IndexWriter should throw a `CorruptIndexException` if the index is corrupted.  You could just handle the exception.

Comment: Exactly. The 'optimal' way to establish the availability of any resource is simply to try to use it, and deal with the exceptions when and if they arise.